# How can I make a class conform to an interface

Tags: typescript

When I say `class Foo implements IFoo` it enforces that *instances* of the class follow the contract.

e.g.

```
interface IFoo { foo: number }
class Foo implements IFoo {
 foo: number
}
const foo = new Foo(); 
// Guaranteed that the following is compatible
const iFoo: IFoo = foo;
```

But what if I want the *class* (not *instances*) to conform to an interface?

Answer (score 2):

Simply do the check with an assignment:

```
interface IFoo { foo: number }
class Foo {
 static foo: number
}
const ensureCompatible:IFoo = Foo; // Check
```

Comment: Posted here because a friend asked me on twitter : https://twitter.com/jesperstarkar/status/776469481052835841 `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Isn't this shocking ? `ensureCompatible:IFoo` means `ensureCompatible` has a property `foo`. Equality means `Foo`, the class/function, has a property `foo`. This is true because `foo` is declared as static in `Foo`. However `foo` is not 'static' in `IFoo`, it s a property of an instance of `IFoo`

Comment: In other words, you cannot use the interface to describe non static properties of `Foo`, and conformance is thus going to be very limited

Comment: @BrunoGrieder - you cannot use the same interface to fully describe two entirely different types. Only to describe what they have in common. If they have nothing in common then the overlap is `{ }`, the empty interface. In JS a class is just a function (requiring the `new` prefix when called). Functions can have properties. So a "class with statics" really declares a `new`-function with properties. It returns "instances of the class" which usually have a totally different type to the function that created them.

Comment: So a class `Foo` declares two types: [1] `Foo`, which is an interface supported by instances of the class, and [2] `typeof Foo`, which is an interface supported by the function `Foo` that creates the instances.

Comment: More complete explanation: http://danielearwicker.github.io/TypeScript_What_is_a_class_.html